# What Does CAS Protect an ASP.NET Application From?

Tags: asp.net, code-access-security

What kind of malicious attack(s) is code access security supposed to protect an ASP.NET application from? Presuming a non-exotic scenerio, an ASP.NET app running on it's own box where you have full control over the application and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS on an ASP.NET server has two main uses:

1. Protect other resources on the server (such as other ASP.NET applications) from potentially malicious server-side code included in any given ASP.NET application.
2. Provide defense-in-depth against potential attacks by users of any given ASP.NET application.

If you are the author of the one and only application hosted on your own server, scenario #1 is probably not particularly interesting to you.  However, the defense-in-depth aspects might be more compelling.  For example, running under medium trust could help thwart an exploit that attempts to read or write to file system locations outside the target application's directory, and that should be interesting even if you're all alone on your own server.

Comment: Thanks, I've got three web applications running which share some assemblies. One is an admin site for highly privileged users, another is a site for internal users, and the third is a public site--all under my control. I'm thinking that CAS could be extremely helpful to add an additional level of security, but everything I've seen is short on examples of real-world use and dives straight into implementation for some hypothetical desktop application located on a shared drive.